# como pegar valor de um autocomplete e mandar para o controller (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, mvc

Tem como receber o valor escolhido de um campo e usar esse valor em uma variável no controller?

Esse é meu campo:

```
<div class="form-group  hidden" id="idnome" > 
    <label>NOME </label>
    <div class="qlyAutoComplete">
        @Html.TextBox("NOME", null, new { @class = "form-control AutoCompletar", 
        maxlength = 50, urlAC = "/RecursosHumanos/PopularPessoa", hidAc = "" })

        @Html.ValidationMessage("NOME", new { @class = "CorVermelhoNegativo" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se o codigo acima estiver dentro um Form e este form for submetido ao controller, basta que na action que voce deseja receber esse valor tenha um parametro chamado Nome.

Olha um simples exemplo

```
Public ActionResult Test(string Nome)
{ Return View(); }
```